# Solar System Model Live Wallpaper

Tags: software-recommendation, themes, customization, desktop-background, 3d

New here (Duh!) and I was checking some live wallpapers that are similar to stuff for the android phones and tablets.

I am looking for a way to have an actual and interactive solar system model as a live wallpaper. I'd even go further with it - zoom and Wikipedia popups for the planets and maybe even a Hubble link that takes you to Hubble's website.

I know there are some shiny galaxy 3d models and planets but I haven't seen a solar system or what I am looking for exactly.

I'll also appreciate it if someone can point me at a project that is like this. If I am not making any sense please feel free to let me know and I will try to be more specific.

Comment: While I think your post makes perfect sense, if you think you can edit it to "try to be more specific," as you say, you might want to go ahead and do so. (I know you already have [an answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/513383/22949), but this may help you get more alternatives.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

open a browser

go to http://www.solarsystemscope.com/

right click the title bar and set layer to 'always on bottom'

press F11 (firefox) to go fullscreen

open your other windows over it